# elasticsearch / kibana wrong epoch date indexing

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

the elastichsearch or kibana is goeing wrong date from epoch index.

```
the date value is: 1495956650 (human date: GMT: Sunday, May 28, 2017 7:30:50 AM)
```

but...
when indexing this record into elasticsearch with below mapping:

```
PUT test
{
    "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "date": {
                    "properties": {
                      "value": {
                        "type": "date"
                      }
                    }
                  }
          }
        }
      }
}
```

when is post this data:

```
POST test/doc
{"date": {
          "value": "1495956650"
        } 
}
```

i see this date in kibana after index pattern, that is wrong!

```
date.value:January 18th 1970, 11:02:36.650
```

my elasticsearch and kibana versions both are 6.2.3
and my system time is update.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like elasticsearch has "guessed" `epoch_millis` instead of `epoch_second`.

You need to adapt your mapping as follows:

```
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "date": {
          "properties": {
            "value": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "epoch_second"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

More information regarding elasticsearch date formats available [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html)